# I am facing a Maven error: "Unknown packaging: bundle". Any suggestions how to resolve it?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, findbugs, pmd, maven-dependency

Anyone knows how to fix this error.

I am trying to analyse my code using maven plugin for finding bugs. I am getting some error with packaging type bundle.

The maven command I am executing is `mvn clean compile site`

I tried adding the maven-bundle-plugin in reporting section, but it did not solve the problem.

```
[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.10.0 from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 16
```

My pom.xml looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
           <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-upload-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                        Enables analysis which takes more memory but finds more bugs.
                        If you run out of memory, changes the value of the effort element
                        to 'low'.
                    -->
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <!-- Produces XML report -->
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please include the complete pom.xml, and your maven command?

Comment: Added the complete pom.xml. My maven command is mvn clean compile site

Comment: Your pom seems to be missing some information, like `artifactId`, `version` and `packaging` for the project itself?

Comment: I removed them on purpose (cannot reveal sensitive information). They are present in the original pom.